# If I use an env var in my Dockerfile, is the env var baked into the image?

Tags: docker

I have a Dockerfile, in which I use an env var as part of my entrypoint command, like this:
`ENTRYPOINT "./docker-entrypoint.sh" ${MY_VAR}`.

Setting `MY_VAR` to different values when I run the containers seems to work, but I don't understand how the image is built without baking in the variable. How are env vars interpolated in images after build?

Comment: Not sure what your question is. It is "baked in", but also you can override when launching container from the image.

Comment: My question is about the mutability of images after build. I thought an image was a static, fixed set of instructions, so I want confirmation that the image instructions can be changed by env vars at run time.

Comment: No, "instructions" can't be changed, but you can override effects of some instructions. For ENV you can set a new value, as we can see. For, say, COPY you can mount another volume at the same path, effectively overwriting container's fs (at that path).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting an `ENV` inside the Dockerfile updates the image configuration (this is some json metadata stored with the image). When you run a container, the image metadata is used to populate the default settings of the container. As they are defaults, you can override the variables as needed from the `docker run` command line or in the compose file. Since you can override them at runtime, these values are not really "baked in" to something like the image unless you use them in a `RUN` command during the image build.

Immutability of images is a reference to the image layers. Once the filesystem layer is created for an image, you cannot modify that layer from docker. You can extend the layer with another layer (replacing or deleting contents from a previous layer). And you can create a new layer and point your image to that new set of layers. However, the contents of a layer as referenced by a sha256 checksum do not get changed by the container or other build steps, allowing layers to be shared among multiple images and containers.

Answer (score 0):

This is the information I was looking for ([docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime)), as Sergio say above some parts of the image that developers may want to set at runtime are overwritable on purpose, and ENTRYPOINT is one of them.